# dnsmasq proxy mode and efi boot

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, dnsmasq

So, I already have DHCP server in my local network. But I want to setup new VMs with network boot (PXE). I've setup dnsmasq in `proxyDHCP` mode to provide PXE info to booting clients while using other DHCP Server for providing IP/MASK.
**Problem:** I was able to setup PXE legacy boot and it works fine, but not EFI boot.
It says "PXE-E18 Server response timeout". Tried that on Hyper-V VM Gen2 and physically connected PC. I see in logs that dnsmaq receives request, but nothing happens...

**So the question is:** is this a dnsmasq issue or what? if it is, then could you please advise some alternatives to this?

**My config if it help**:

```
tftp-root=/opt/pxeboot/tftpboot
enable-tftp

dhcp-vendorclass=BIOS,PXEClient:Arch:00000
dhcp-vendorclass=UEFI,PXEClient:Arch:00007

dhcp-boot=net:UEFI,uefi/bootx64.efi
dhcp-boot=net:BIOS,pxelinux.0

dhcp-no-override
pxe-prompt="Press F8 for boot menu", 1
pxe-service=X86PC, "Boot Legacy PXE", pxelinux

dhcp-range=192.168.1.99,proxy
```

**edit**

```
Feb 19 16:17:56 dnsmasq-dhcp[16026]: 2483890568 vendor class: PXEClient:Arch:00007:????:??????
Feb 19 16:17:56 dnsmasq-dhcp[16026]: 2483890568 PXE(eth0) 00:15:5d:21:94:0a proxy
Feb 19 16:17:56 dnsmasq-dhcp[16026]: 2483890568 tags: UEFI, eth0
Feb 19 16:17:56 dnsmasq-dhcp[16026]: 2483890568 bootfile name: uefi/bootx64.efi
```

So client arch is 7

All files is in place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check  DHCP Option 93 at [RFC 4578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4578)

```
        Type   Architecture Name
        ----   -----------------
          0    Intel x86PC
          1    NEC/PC98
          2    EFI Itanium
          3    DEC Alpha
          4    Arc x86
          5    Intel Lean Client
          6    EFI IA32                             < x86
          7    EFI BC                               < x86_64
          8    EFI Xscale
          9    EFI x86-64                           < x86_64
```

you forgot to consider the type 9 at your dnsmasq config. If your x86_64 client announces type 9 within its DHCP option 93 the request will be ignored by the proxyDHCP.

To see what's really going on just run  Wireshark capture.

Please see I have edited your question; a proxyDHCP provides only PXE info only to PXE clients.

Comment: here is piece of my log (see in edited question)

Comment: I'd run a wireshark capture...

Comment: found similar question http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2014q1/008179.html here, it looks like that this won't work in proxymode :(

Comment: I have read the whole thread (http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2015q4/009907.html) and I'm shocked; those guys are completely lost; UEFI perfectly supports proxyDHCP w/o using option 60, also using option 43 when not necessary makes no sense. If I were I'd look away from dnsmasq; Sorry I didn't know they were having this kind of unresolved problems.

Comment: so is there any known alternatives? I only need pxe server for legacy boot and uefi boot :)

Comment: Sorry for not answering before, I do not know a Linux alternative for proxyDHCP